# Put, Delete Method is not wokring. error : HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webapi

Get, Post methods are working, but I'm going to run the Put and Delete request then I face an error message.

Complete Project Url : https://github.com/Dushyantsingh-ds/dotnet-issues/blob/main/Projects/EmployeeService/Readme.md

[image]

Comment: This question is missing a [mcve]. We can't possibly tell you what is wrong without the controller code. Note the [mcve] docs section on "complete": _"Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem **in the question itself**"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete endpoint should also have a `[Route(...)]` data annotation:

```
[Route("api/employee/{EmpId}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to decide what are you going to use - attribute routing or default routing from config file.

For today the most common way to use API is to assign attribute routing to the controller

```
[Route("~/api/[controller]/[action]]
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
```

you can use  https//localhost:44350/api/employee/get for Get()

and so on

```
 // /api/employee/get
 public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()

// /api/employee/get/5 
[HttpGet("{empId}")]
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(int empId)

 //   /api/employee/post" for 
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Employee employee)

  // /api/employee/delete/5   
[Route("{empId}")]
 public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int empId)

 // /api/employee/put/5   
[Route("{empId}")]
 public HttpResponseMessage Put(int empId, [FromBody] Employee employee)
```

and since you don't put methods as action attributes , you don't need to use delete and put, you can use get and post instead.